# How to compute similarity score between two images using their feature vectors?

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, keras, pattern-recognition

I am working on face recognition project using deep learning architecture to classify the images into respective classes. The output of network at softmax layer is the predicted class label and the output of last but one layer at the dense layer is a feature representation of the input image. Here the feature vector is a 1-D matrix of size 1000 for each image. Predicting classes is recognition type problem, but I'm interested in verification problem.

So given two sample images, I need to compare the similarity/dissimilarity score between two given images using their feature representations. If the **match score is greater than the threshold** then it's a **hit** else no hit. Please let me know if there are any standard approaches?

Example of similar faces (which should ideally generate matchscore>threshold): https://3c1703fe8d.site.internapcdn.net/newman/gfx/news/hires/2014/yvyughbujh.jpg

Comment: "image similarity" is by no mean a trivial defintion and therefore a very fragmented task. The human brain has still many advantages there, compared to computer vision.

Comment: I'm working on LFW dataset, so similarity here refers to the matching scores in biometrics point of view. Training the classifier and classification is a recognition problem. But here I'm trying to solve verification type problem.

Comment: can you add some sample images of similar and dissimilar images? What kind of "feature vectors" are present, you mentioned them in the title.

Comment: Mentioned in the edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project has two solutions:

- Train your own network (using pretrained one) with output in 1000 classes. This approach is not the simplest one because of the necessity of having enough (say huge) amount of data for each class, approximately 1000 samples per class.
- Another approach is to use Distance Metrics Learning. By this "distance" we usually mean Euclidean norm. This approach is much wider and deeper than just extract features and match them to the nearest one. Try to search for it.
  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The second approach you've mentioned makes sense and is efficient to implement. So by this approach can we clearly distinguish between the images of the same class and different classes? Are the inter-class and intra-class distances clearly distinguishable?

Comment: In most cases, yes, they will be distinguishable. But anyway, it completely depends on kind of object you want to distinguish. Incase of faces it is a solvable task.